# How to bind the content first before sending an email as one message?

Tags: c#, email, datatable

I have a problem with regards to sending email as one message. The code  reads all of the content from the database but it doesn't send the message as one in the email. It sends repeatedly by how much row/s or data in the database. How can i bind first the content and send it to the email as one?

```
  int Quantity = 0;
    string JobName;
    string OrderType;
    DateTime DueDate;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);

    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Shopping_Cart WHERE UID=@UIDD";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UIDD", hfUserID.Value);


    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] {
                        new DataColumn("QUANTITY", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn("JOB NAME", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("ORDER TYPE", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("DUE DATE", typeof(DateTime))});

    //===== Execute Query.
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (Session["UID"] != null)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Quantity = dr.GetInt32(4);
            JobName = dr.GetString(10);
            OrderType = dr.GetString(17);
            DueDate = dr.GetDateTime(9);

            dt.Rows.Add(Quantity, JobName, OrderType, DueDate);
        }
        StringBuilder YourTable = new StringBuilder();
        YourTable.Append("Thank you for choosing Junand's Labels Inc. Your order will be evaluated by the manager with the maximum of (3 days). Please wait for the confirmation of the manager in your email whether your order will be acceptable or not. The price will be announced once the order has been accepted. ");
        YourTable.Append("<br>");
        YourTable.Append("<br>");
        YourTable.Append("Order Review");
        YourTable.Append("<table border = '1'>");
        YourTable.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            YourTable.Append("<th style = 'background-color: #0bd2d1;color:#ffffff'>");
            YourTable.Append(column.ColumnName);
            YourTable.Append("</th>");
        }
        YourTable.Append("</tr>");


        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            YourTable.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                YourTable.Append("<td>");
                YourTable.Append(row[column]);
                YourTable.Append("</td>");

            }
            YourTable.Append("</tr>");
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.Body += YourTable;
            message.To.Add(Session["Email"].ToString());
            message.From = new MailAddress("junandscontactus@gmail.com");
            message.Subject = "View your Orders";

            message.IsBodyHtml = true;



            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("u@gmail.com", "password");

            client.Send(message);

        }

    }
```

[Here is the sample output in the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Jvs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the sending of the email

```
  client.Send(message);
```

outside of the

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
```

loop.